# How to write ruby script that uses the production environment instead of development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have writen a ruby script that requires `config/environment.rb` so I can use all the models of my rails application in the script but the problem is that I want to use the `production` environment instead of the `develoment` environment which seems to be the default behavior.

Im using Rails 3.1.1 and Ruby 1.9.2

How can I run the script with the `production` environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script will take the environment variable RAILS_ENV as the environment to use.

I'd be very wary of overriding that in the script as it may cause much confusion if you try and run your script in another environment - e.g. staging - and it starts trying to access production databases etc.

So do either:

```
RAILS_ENV=production ./script/my-awesome-script
```

or

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
./script/my-awesome-script
```

Generally speaking; when I log into a production Rails environment I'd be changing the environment straight away if I haven't configured it to be "production" by default.

Comment: Thank you so much! `RAILS_ENV=production ./script/my-awesome-script` is the only one that worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want either `Rails.env = 'production'` or `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'` in your script.

Answer (score 0):

@davidb, I am not sure what u want also not as good on rails yet but may be you can use the seed.rb (i.e seed functionality) for achieving what you want if this script is run only once or sometimes as we can specify the environment while running seed

rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production